# How to store types, their subtype information all together in binary search tree data structure?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Edited:

To explain my question more in depth. Let's say I have a tool A. Inside tool A there are subtypes of it such as A, B, C, D etc. and each subtype has a quantity.

```
Tool A
there are several specific types available in tool A
S.no.   name                quantity
1.    charger                   5
2.    electronic stuff.        10
...
9. so on                       20
```

I want to use binary search to store these values somehow. So when user choose the option tool A, it display all the specific types of things available in them with the quantity and the user can borrow any of these tools and hence the above data can be updated depending upon how much user borrow and return those stuff later. Is there any way to do that using the help of binary search tree?

What I have done till now is:

My code:

public class Tools
    {

```
    private string name;
    private string toolInfo;
    private int quantity;


    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }

    }

    public string ToolInfo
    {
        get { return toolInfo; }
        set
        {
            toolInfo = value;
        }

    }


    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
        }

    }


    public Tools(string name, string toolInfo, int quantity) {

        this.name = name;
        this.toolInfo = toolInfo;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void toolsInfo()
    {
        //tools info
        WriteLine("Tool name: " + name + " Tool info: " + toolInfo + " Quantity: " + quantity);
    }

    public void addTools()
    {
        //add tools
    }


    public void borrowTools()
    {
        //borrow tools
    }


}
```

}

//main class

```
Tools tool1 = new Tools("gardening", "gardening tools...", 40);
            Tools tool2 = new Tools("flooring", "forring tools...", 20);
            Tools tool3 = new Tools("fencing", "fencing tools..", 50);
            Tools tool4 = new Tools("measuring", "measurng tools...", 10);
            Tools tool5 = new Tools("cleaning", "cleaning tools...", 20);
            Tools tool6 = new Tools("painting", "painting tools...", 60);
            Tools tool7 = new Tools("electronic", "electronic tools...", 5);
            Tools tool8 = new Tools("automative", "automative tools..", 20);
            Tools tool9 = new Tools("electricity", "electrucity tools...", 10);'
```

But that only store the types of tools, how could I attach the subtypes to each of the tool them as well  in a way so I can manipulate/change their name or values etc. depending on the user input or some condition?

Comment: Not sure this will solve your problem, but you can think of each node as belonging to two separate trees (or any other data structure). One tree has the initial data structure you had in mind, and the other has connections to related items. For instance: each node belongs to the tree you have in mind AND also to a clique of related items (painting, electronic, etc..). This way you can find your tool and from there easily find all other topic related tools

Comment: @shapiroyaacov Is it possible if you can write some code or something in answer so it's easy to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Is the binary search a prerequisite? You can approach the problem in a different and simpler way.

You can create a new class (e.g. `ToolsContainer`) that contains sets of `Tools`. This way you can have a Dictionary that stores key-value pairs that have as a key the Tool type and as a value another Dictionary of tool subtypes and tools. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Your existing code goes here

public class ToolsContainer
{
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Tools>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Tools>>();

    public ToolsContainer()
    {
    }

    public void add(Tools t)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Tools> nested = null;

        // Check if key exists. If it does update it,
        // else create new entry
        if(dict.TryGetValue(t.Name, out nested))
            nested[t.ToolInfo] = t;
        else
        {
            dict[t.Name] = new Dictionary<string, Tools>();
            dict[t.Name][t.ToolInfo] = t;
        }
    }

    public void printData()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, Tools>> toolsType in dict)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Tools> tool in toolsType.Value)
                 Console.WriteLine("Type = {0}, Tool = {1}, Quantity = {2}", toolsType.Key, tool.Key, tool.Value.Quantity);
         }
    }
}
```

And test it using the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ToolsContainer c = new ToolsContainer();
        // Add new keys
        c.add(new Tools("gardening", "gardeningTool1", 50));
        c.add(new Tools("automotive","automotiveTool1", 20));
        // Update existing key
        c.add(new Tools("gardening", "gardeningTool1", 40));
        c.printData();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type = gardening, Tool = gardeningTool1, Quantity = 40
Type = automotive, Tool = automotiveTool1, Quantity = 20
```

Using the above approach you can insert new tools and update existing ones. You can also expand on this and use LINQ to order by the data (e.g. order by quantity).

Comment: Yeah, I mean I need to use binary search specially to search the values inside the data structure or while updating, deleting or addiing.

Comment: If binary search is a prerequisite the above cannot be used. You'll have to keep the data in a sorted array, that will be updated in each action.

Comment: Ah, so instead of Dictionary I can use SortedArray, right?

Comment: Yeah maybe a sorted array or a SortedList with a custom comparator that will sort by name or quantity, on which you can then apply the binary search algorithm. By the way if you want a binary array TREE, you'll have to implement some kind of Node struct that will be traversed. It is different to simple binary search algorithm. The first one is a container, while the second an algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah I need to apply binary search algorithm I think